# Excel chart - counting the series and then adding a data label to the last point

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, charts

I've managed to make a macro that finds the last point of the first series in a chart and add and format a data label. I would now like to make it count the series, which may change in number, in the chart and iterate through each one doing what it did to series 1.

It fails miserably. I've commented out the parts that I tried but failed.

I'm not sure how I wrap a loop around what I've done.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Michael.

```
Dim MyChart As Chart
Dim ChartPoints As Points
Dim ChartDataLables As DataLabel
'Dim NumberOfSeries As Series

Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

'Set NumberOfSeries = MyChart.SeriesCollection.Count

Set ChartPoints = MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points
ChartPoints(ChartPoints.Count).ApplyDataLabels
Set ChartDataLables = ChartPoints(ChartPoints.Count).DataLabel

 'For Each NumberOfSeries In MyChart
 With MyChart
     With ChartDataLables
    .Position = xlLabelPositionRight
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Font.Size = 8
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    .ShowSeriesName = True
    .Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
     End With
 End With
  'Next NumberOfSeries
 End Sub
```

My original macro was written with the help of Google/Forums and trial and error.

Comment: I wrote this tutorial on my blog: [Label Last Point for Excel 2007](http://peltiertech.com/label-last-point-for-excel-2007/).

Comment: @JonPeltier Many thanks. I knew I should have checked your site more closely.

Answer (score 1):

No need for VBA (unless you like VBA).  Just create a helper series that evaluates if there's another value (I use an offset formula).  If there is no "next" value in your data series, then return the current/last value.  Otherwise, return an #N/A.  Then add this helper series to your chart, and label/format to taste.  The chart ignores all of the N/A's and only plots the final data point.  This can also be used to find other key values (e.g. first, high, low, etc...).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I really like this idea, and I'll try to implement it in some of my future charts.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each series in the chart -

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoopThroughSeries()
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Dim mySeries As Series

    With myChart
        For Each mySeries In myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
            'do stuff
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies. I've been busy working on another project so haven't been able to implement your advice. But I will be going back to this problem. Thanks.